# Native Base change floatlabel input bottom outline color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

[image]

I am using react native with native base theme engine. I customized most of the native base elements. I am trying to change the color of border which i pointed in above picture.

I tried to change in components/Item.js

```
".floatingLabel": {
  "NativeBase.Input": {
    height: 50,
    top: 8,
   borderColor: 'red'
  },
  "NativeBase.Label": {
    top: 8
  },
  "NativeBase.Icon": {
    top: 6
  }
},
```

And tried to add border manually in Input.js but its not working. There is not much of help online for this. Is this possible?

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/611) by giving the `style` directly to the `item `

Comment: Not helpful, i want to do it on floatlabel input

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change bottom border color of all floating label Items, add borderColor inside ".floatingLabel":{}

```
".floatingLabel": {
  "NativeBase.Input": {
    height: 50,
    top: 8
  },
  "NativeBase.Label": {
    top: 8
  },
  "NativeBase.Icon": {
    top: 6
  },
  borderColor: "blue"
},
```

For a single item just override the style of the `<Item/>`

```
<Item floatingLabel style={{ borderColor:"blue" }}>
     <Label>Username</Label>
     <Input />
</Item>
```